# WHMCS : How to add domain checker in configurable options

Tags: whmcs, whmcs-invoice-template

Now i'm looking to add a domain checker on configurable options (WHMCS) but i didn't found it,

Can someone help me please.

Best regards.

Comment: I am not sure : go to Setup Menu -> Products/Services -> Products/Services; then choose your product then check the box  ´Tick to show domain registration option´

Comment: yes i already add this and it's work, but i want to add the script of choose domain to configurable options page, this is my issue? can u help me pls